# Data returning from $http.get() is not sequence

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to fetch data from 3 source URLs different only by id. The result I am getting is fine but not in sequence. My code is :
    
    `var data = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}];
    var get = [];
    for(i=0;i<(data.length);i++){
    $http.get("server URL"+data[i].id)
    .success(function(data) { 
    get.push(data);
    })
    .error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    }); 
    }$scope.data= get;`
    
I have done researches and tried things too but could not make it work right.
I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992933/random-sequence-of-response-in-http-get) link but not so useful for me.

Comment: Can you snapshot the result pls ?

Comment: I have used a demo of my code so I can't post my actual code's demo. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) for this.

```
var data = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}],
    promises = [];

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    promises.push($http.get("server URL"+data[i].id));

$q.all(promises)
    .then(function(result) {
        $scope.data = result;
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

The result will be an array with results **in order** of requests.

Comment: I am getting promises.then is not a function error. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Atula Sorry, I've updated my answer, I forgot `q.all`

Comment: Thank you so much @Martijn, It is working all fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following:

```
var data = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}];
var get = [];
var i = 0;
function loadDataInSequence(){
  if(i<data.length){
    $http.get("server URL"+data[i].id)
        .success(function(data) { 
                get[i] = data;//calling callback
            loadDataInSequence();
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
        i++;
  }
}
$scope.data= get;
```

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of situations, there a library called [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).
You can use async parallel in place of for loop.
There are also helpers like series, and limit for different kind of requirements.